# Show that for all $X \in \mathscr{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ we have that: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\left(I + \frac{1}{m}X\right)}^{m} = \exp{X}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, solution-verification, matrix-calculus

Show that for all $X \in \mathscr{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ we have that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\left(I + \frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m}} = \exp{X}$$

Note that for matrices, the $e^X$ is defined by using the series expansion of the exponential function:

$$\exp{X} = I + X + \frac{1}{2!}X + \frac{1}{3!}X + \cdots$$

---

I expanded out $\left(I + \frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m}$, which I figured I could do since powers of $X$ commute with each other:

$$\left(I + \frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m} = \sum_{k=0}^{m}{\binom{m}{k}\left(\frac{1}{m}X\right)^{k}} = \sum_{k=0}^{m}{\frac{m!}{k!\left(m-k\right)!}\left(\frac{1}{m^{k}}X^{k}\right)}$$

The $k$'th term in this expansion is can be simplified to:

$$\frac{m\left(m-1\right)\left(m-2\right)\cdots\left(m-k+1\right)}{m^{k}}\frac{1}{k!}X^{k}$$ (edited)

Thus, as $m \rightarrow \infty$, the identity will hold since $\frac{m\left(m-1\right)\left(m-2\right)\cdots\left(m-k-1\right)}{m^{k}} \underset{m\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$

Comment: I believe it should be $(m-k+1)$. But anyway, you're missing a key step. Why are you allowed to simply take the limits in that way when you're dealing with sums? Explicitly, you have the expression $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{[0,m]}(k)\frac{m(m-1)\cdots (m-k+1)}{m^k}\cdot \frac{X^k}{k!}$. You now wish to take the limit as $m\to\infty$, so the question becomes why are you allowed to interchange the limit $m\to\infty$ with the series? (you're right that for each summand, the limit is $1$, but note that the number of terms is also increasing).

Comment: So, you can either appeal to Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, which would be my approach (what's the dominating function?). Or you could try to be more careful with estimates and derive a uniform estimate which would give a more elementary (but tedious) justification for the swap.

Comment: I think in your first comment the upper limit should be $m$ instead of $\infty$? Could I just use the exponential function as the dominating function?

Comment: no, the upper limit is $\infty$ because I included the indicator $\mathbf{1}_{[0,m]}$. But no the exponential isn't a dominating function (you need a function $a:\Bbb{N}\to[0,\infty)$, i.e a sequence of numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k<\infty$ and such that for all $m$, $\left|\mathbf{1}_{[0,m]}(k)\frac{m(m-1)\cdots (m-k+1)}{m^k}\frac{X^k}{k!}\right|\leq a_k$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach based on the matrix logarithm. For $\|A\|<1$ we have the power series form $\log(I+A)=\sum_{k\geq1}(-1)^{k+1}A^k/k$, so for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $$\log\left((I+X/n)^n\right)=n\log(I+X/n)=n[X/n+o(1/n)]=X+o(1).$$
The desired result follows by the continuity of the matrix exponential.

Comment: I'm not good at the big o and little o notation >.<

Comment: @NobelCat the idea is that the log expansion gives $\log(I+A)=A-A^2/2+\dots$, then when we plug in $A=X/n$ we get $\log(I+X/n)=X/n-(X/n)^2+\dots$. Multiply this by $n$, and we can write the sum as $X+\frac{1}{n}\cdot\text{some bounded function}$. P.S. I would try to get more comfortable with big/little O notation, it can make analysis easier, cleaner and more intuitive :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $ m\in\mathbb{N} $, we have the following : \begin{aligned}\exp{X}-\left(I+\frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m}=\sum_{n=m+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}X^{n}}+\sum_{n=0}^{m}{\left(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{m^{n}}\binom{m}{n}\right)X^{n}}\end{aligned}

Let $ \left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert$, be a sub-multiplicative norm of $ \mathscr{M}_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right) $, then : $$ \left\Vert\exp{X}-\left(I+\frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m}\right\Vert\leq\left\Vert\sum_{n=m+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}X^{n}}\right\Vert+\sum_{n=0}^{m}{\left(1-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)}\right)\frac{\left\Vert X\right\Vert^{n}}{n!}} $$

Notice that, for all $ n\in\mathbb{N} $,

$ 1-\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^{j-1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)}-\prod\limits_{k=0}^{j}{\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)}\right)}=\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{j\prod\limits_{k=0}^{j-1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)}}\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \tiny \ \ \ \ \normalsize\leq\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{j}=\frac{1}{m}\binom{n}{2} $

Thus : $$ \left\Vert\exp{X}-\left(I+\frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m}\right\Vert\leq\left\Vert\sum_{n=m+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}X^{n}}\right\Vert+\frac{\left\Vert X\right\Vert^{2}}{2m}\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}{\frac{\left\Vert X\right\Vert^{n}}{n!}}\underset{m\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Hence, $ \left(I+\frac{1}{m}X\right)^{m}\underset{m\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\exp{X} $.